# Get child by it's parent's another child

Tags: html, xpath

My HTML looks like that:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="url">
        <a href="http://url.com/view/12">LINK</a>
    </div>

    <div class="stats">
        <div class="a">12</div>
        <div class="b">14</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="url">
        <a href="http://url.com/view/364">LINK</a>
    </div>

    <div class="stats">
        <div class="a">133</div>
        <div class="b">13</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="url">
        <a href="http://url.com/view/24324">LINK</a>
    </div>

    <div class="stats">
        <div class="a">4</div>
        <div class="b">46</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is this possible to get parent's child which is found by another, the same parent child?

So, I want to get contents of class `b` of second parent. But I want to find bu it's `href` parameter.

Like that-

- XPath finds parent, which has child `url` and `a` with `href` parameter `http://url.com/view/364`
- XPath takes contents of class `b` in the same parent

If you don't understand, I basically need that XPath gets number `13` (contents of `b`), but find it using `href` parameter.

Is this possible? How this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An even cleaner approach is (line break only for readability)

```
//div[@class = 'parent' and div[@class = 'url']
/a/@href = 'http://url.com/view/364']/div[@class = 'stats']/div[@class = 'b']
```

It is better than the answer you found yourself (actually, it's a good thing you found an answer yourself!) because there are no unnecessary parent axis (`..`) steps in it.

It is better than

```
(//a[@href='http://url.com/view/364']/following::div[@class='b'])[1]
```

because `following::div[@class = 'b']` selects a `div` element that follows the context item, even if it is in another `div[@class = 'parent']`. For instance, if the document looked like

```
<html>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="url">
        <a href="http://url.com/view/364">LINK</a>
    </div>

    <div class="stats">
        <div class="a">133</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="url">
        <a href="http://url.com/view/24324">LINK</a>
    </div>

    <div class="stats">
        <div class="a">4</div>
        <div class="b">46</div>
    </div>
</div>
</html>
```

then the result would be

```
<div class="b">46</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

It is easy to do that -

```
//*[@class="parent"]/div[@class="url"]/a[@href="http://url.com/view/364"]/../../div[@class="stats"]/div[@class="b"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, a cleaner approach would be to use the [`following`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following) axis and then select the first node with `class='b'`.

```
"(//a[@href='http://url.com/view/364']/following::div[@class='b'])[1]"
```